# How to include heteroscedasticity in copula modelling

Tags: programming, garch, copula, multivariate

I have a dataset of 9 variables and I want to fit a t-copula to them in order to construct a multivariate and after that resample from it.
I am using Matlab.

```
rng default  % For reproducibility
[Rho, nu] = copulafit('t',[A B C D E F G H L],'Method', 'ML'); 
r = copularnd('t',Rho,nu,1000); % I resample 1000 sample from it
```

once resample I use the *icdf* to obtain the time series of the sample data

```
a = ksdensity(data(:,1),r(:,1),'function','icdf');
...
l = ksdensity(data(:,9),r(:,9),'function','icdf');
```

after this command i get a warning on the convergence such as:

```
Warning: Inverse CDF calculation did not converge for p = 0.001161.
```

this happens for 3 out of 9 variables. Assuming *a* is working fine and *l* gives me the warning, for *a* the max and min values are aligned with those of the original raw data *data(:,1)*, while for *l* they are about *1e+7*. Which is non-sense.
Therefore I have checked the original data, for *data(:,1)* and *data(:,9)* and look like this

[image]

[image]

the second looks very very heteroskedastic compared to the first so I assume a t-copula is not suitable for that.
My questions then are:

is the copula a tool only for stationary time series?
in case of high heteroskedasticity, is there a way to model it for example with a conditional copula?

I would prefer if you could refer to python or Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will help solve your convergence issue, but a standard way of incorporating conditional heteroskedasticity in copula models is to build a copula-GARCH model. Each time series is first modelled with GARCH, and then the standardized innovations from the GARCH models of all the series are jointly modelled with a copula.

Comment: ok thanks. In this way the innovations will be iid and a copula can fit well in such conditions, is that right?

Comment: @Luigi87, yes, if the GARCH models for all series adequately capture their conditional heteroskedasticity, this will be the case.

Comment: @Luigi87, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Comment: becasue I was asking for a reference code as well. Also if I fit a garch the output is a garch version of original signal so the data does not become stationary..so the conceptual question was if it is still correct to fit a copula onto a nonstationary signal

Comment: @Luigi87, asking for code is off topic, but you may look for it on websites of authors of papers involving copula-GARCH models. `rugarch` manual and vignette may help, too. I have no idea if anyone still uses Matlab for GARCH, but if the functionality is there, there should also be some examples out there. Regarding fitting a copula onto a nonstationary signal, this is not what you do. You fit it on standardized residuals from GARCH, and these are iid. Conceptually this is correct.